# analyse a .aspx site with paging with __doPostBack function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jsoup, paging, dopostback

I want to analyse some data of a webpage, but here's the problem: the site has more pages which gets called with a __doPostBack function.

How can I "simulate" to go a page further and analyse this site, and so on..

At this time I analyse the data with JSoup in java - but I'm open to use some other language if it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an automation library which is [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org), which you can use in a lot of languages (C#, Java, Perl,...)

For more information how to start this link is very helpful: [this.](http://www.bitmotif.com/selenium/selenium-remote-control-for-java-a-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

A postback-based system (.NET, Prado/PHP, etc) works in a manner that it keeps a complete snapshot of the browser contents on the server side. This is called a pagestate. Any attempt to manipulate with a client that is not JavaScript-capable is almost sure to fail.

What you need is a JavaScript-capable browser. The easiest solution I found is to use the framework Firefox is written in - [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XUL) - to create such a desktop application. What you do is basically create a desktop application with a single browser element in it, which you can then script from the application itself without restrictions of the security container. Alternatively, you could also use the [Greasemonkey plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to do your bidding. The latter is a bit easier to get started with, but it's fairly limited since it's running on a per-page basis.

With both solutions you then have access to the page's DOM to gather data and you can also fire events (like clicking on a button). Unfortunately you have to learn JavaScript for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

As well as Selenium, you can use http://watin.org/